# Spray Akka REST service with MongoDB how to learn

Tags: mongodb, scala, rest, spray

A few days ago i'm starting to learn scala. Now I would like to build some rest server with spray. I'm looking for some materials for learning this. I found this https://dzone.com/articles/building-rest-service-scala but I think it's outdated. What materials do you recommend to study these issues some books, tutorials, video?

Comment: Spray itself is outdated. Its no longer being developed. It has been merged into akka project and is now called akka-http.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You recommend some tutorials rest, mongodb in akka-http?

Comment: I found this: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/restful-web-services-scala it's good?

Comment: If you are not familiar with the syntax of scala or the concepts of functional programming, it will be a hard way to go and I can only suggest you to start with a Scala basics tutorial.
Maybe this is interesting for you: https://github.com/shekhargulati/52-technologies-in-2016/blob/master/01-finatra/README.md

Comment: Ok, thanks. Very good repo!